# SharePoint Online with OneDrive Sync in Windows 10 recently synced file is available only after a minute

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, sharepoint-search, onedrive, sharepoint-site

I have configured `One Drive Sync` with `SharePoint Online` and the syncing is working fine, but the file is available in the search only after a minute.

[image]

So, my question is, how can I make this real-time? Are there any kind of [flow or something like that](https://emea.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I remember when search results used to take hours to show. No there are no controls to make it go faster. One minute is impressive considering how much new content is being added to OneDrive daily.

What is your use case?

Comment: My use case is that the other user should be able to get the files in search once the file is uploaded.

Comment: They can after a minute. The alternative is to share it when you upload it and it will be made available in "Shared with me".